# Values loss for copy() for Kotlin data class

Tags: kotlin

I have such `data class`:

```kotlin
data class BookObject(
    val description: String?,

    val owningCompanyData: OwningCompanyData?,
) {
    var id: String? = null
    var createdAt: Instant? = null
    var createdBy: String? = null
    var modifiedAt: Instant? = null

    fun update(command: CreateOrUpdateBookObjectCommand): BookObject =
        this.copy(
            description = command.description,
            owningCompanyData = command.owningCompanyData
        )
}
```

When I use the `update` function for an object with completely filled fields, I get an object with empty `id`, `createdAt`, `createdBy`, `modifiedAt` fields (they become equal to `null`). But why is this happening? Why do these fields lose their values?

[The kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html#copying) says:

> Use the copy() function to copy an object, allowing you to alter some
> of its properties while **keeping the rest unchanged**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer actually is present in your link, located in [the paragraph just before "Copying"](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html#properties-declared-in-the-class-body).

> The compiler only uses the properties defined inside the primary constructor for the automatically generated functions.